# How can I set the outline colour and thickness of MuiButton-outlined using the MuiThemeProvider wrapper and theme overrides?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using React and the Material-UI API, I have wrapped the root component with `<MuiThemeProvider>` and I have been successful customising various attributes in my theme so i think it is set up correctly. My problem is I can't seem to change the colour and thickness of the outline for the button: `MuiButton-outlinedPrimary`. I suspect I am using the wrong target names and the documentation is not clear.

Here is my theme:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {                              
    primary: {
      light: '#93D1FF',
      main: '#00A1DF',
      dark: '#005F95'
    }
  },
  typography: {
    body2: {
      fontSize: '.7rem'
    },
    caption: {
      fontSize: '.6rem'
    },
    overrides: {               
      MuiButton: {                      // Here is where I am trying to target
        outlinedPrimary: {              // the MuiButton outline property
          color: '#00A1DF',             // but it does not work!!!
          border: '3px solid #00A1DF'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

export default theme;
```

I'm trying to set the outline so that it is the same colour as pallette.primary.main, I am invoking the component like this: `<Button variant="outlined" color="primary">`
There just doesn't seem to be much in the way of examples on the internet and the documentation is vague. If anyone could shed some light I would be grateful.

Thanks,
Dan.

Comment: Your `overrides` are nested inside of `typography` -- they shouldn't be.

Comment: OMG!!! It's been a long day man! Thank's for that!